# curl ca-cert error installing Meteor on Mac

Tags: curl, ssl, meteor

I am trying: 
curl --insecure  https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

and I get: curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

I tried --insecure after failing without the parameter.

I tried using also the only cert found by locate in my system:
curl --cacert '/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ca-certificates.crt'

Any ideas of how I can get those certs or properly install meteor without this problems?

## Temporary Solution:

I have found some posts Meteor's github [issue tracker](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/348), of people reporting similar proplems. There is a temporary solution in case you really want to jump into meteor without caring much about the certs stuff.

So, curl is not working with the https urls where they load the data from. I download the shell script, and modified a bit.

If you open http://install.meteor.com/ with your browser, you will see the .sh script. Then, you can edit this script [I guess you see where I am going with this].

I did something more handy,

line [63-69]:

```
TARBALL_URL="https://d3fm2vapipm3k9.cloudfront.net/bootstrap/0.6.4/meteor-bootstrap-${PLATFORM}.tar.gz"

INSTALL_TMPDIR="$HOME/.meteor-install-tmp"
rm -rf "$INSTALL_TMPDIR"
mkdir "$INSTALL_TMPDIR"
echo "Downloading Meteor distribution"
curl --progress-bar --fail "$TARBALL_URL" | tar -xzf - -C "$INSTALL_TMPDIR"
```

Follow TARBALL_URL with other resource than curl, and download that tgz. Uncompress in ~/, and you will have directory ~/.meteor

Running this part of the script: lines[75-84]

```
test -x "$HOME/.meteor/meteor"

echo
echo "Meteor 0.6.4 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor)."

LAUNCHER="$HOME/.meteor/tools/latest/launch-meteor"

if cp "$LAUNCHER" "$PREFIX/bin/meteor" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Writing a launcher script to $PREFIX/bin/meteor for your convenience."
  cat <<"EOF"
```

will add the launcher.

Then meteor is added in your bin path. 
BOOM. After spending 2hs fighting with certs, now enjoy and write your Meteor app in 5 minutes :) Amazing framework!

Cheers

Comment: $PREFIX needs to be replaced with /usr/local since only part of the script is executed

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.
It seems to be due the Anaconda-specific curl executable.

What I simply did was to let the curl in /usr/bin be the first choice to the meteor installer.
You can do that by doing:

```
  $ export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
  $ curl https://install.meteor.com | sh
```

If you need again Anaconda python to be first, close the terminal and open it again.

cheers!

Comment: We bumped into this problem also after installing Meteor as it uses curl under the hood to download new versions IIRC.

Answer (score 7):

First save the script using following command.

`curl -k "https://install.meteor.com/" > meteor.sh
vi meteor.sh`

Add -k to curl in following line to turn off curl's verification of the certificate in the script.

`curl -k --progress-bar --fail "$TARBALL_URL" | tar -xzf - -C "$INSTALL_TMPDIR"`

Than Run following command.

`sh meteor.sh`

Comment: I helped in my case, but now the similar issue with other packets. Downloading meteor-tool... takes to long for example

Answer (score 2):

Changing from https to http in line 63 :
`TARBALL_URL="https://d3fm2vapipm3k9.cloudfront.net/bootstrap/0.6.4/meteor-bootstrap-${PLATFORM}.tar.gz"` 
will do.

Comment: This should NOT be a recommended solution as this increases the likelihood of installing something via a man-in-the-middle attack.  There are better methods.

Comment: Worked for me..If you are worried, download the tarball via browser, put in your own server and point to it...But still, It's a workaround..